# Question about calculation of higher-order infinitesimal

Tags: calculus, limits

I wonder given x $\neq$ 0, whether the following equalities hold or not reespectively:

$$\frac{o(x^2)}{x}=o(x),\quad \frac{o(x^2)}{o(x)}=o(x)$$ 
, where $o(\cdot)$ means higher-order infinitesimal, i.e. given both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are infinitesimal, if $\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$, then we can denote $f(x)=o(g(x))$.

I think that the second equality should be right, because we have $o(f(x))o(g(x))=o(f(x)g(x))$, but I have no idea about the first one, neither proof nor example. Could anyone show me a proof or some examples?

Answer (score 1):

Let us take a look at the first claim. We see that 
$$ \frac{\frac{o(x^2)}{x}}{x} \; = \; \frac{o(x^2)}{x^2}$$
which tends to $0$ as $x \to x_0$ by definition of $o(x^2)$. Hence, $\frac{o(x^2)}{x}=o(x)$.
Now, for the second claim, consider the functions $x\mapsto x^3$, $x\mapsto x^2$ and $x_0=0$. What does this simple example tell us?